# Why I am not able to find the duplicate number and the next missing element after the duplicate number in Python?

Tags: python, list, set

I have a set of integers s, which originally contains all the numbers from 1 to n. Unfortunately, due to some error, one of the numbers in s got duplicated to another number in the set, which results in repetition of one number and loss of another number.

You are given an integer array nums representing the data status of this set after the error.

Find the number that occurs twice and the number that is missing and return them in the form of an array. **For example , for this input  nums=[1,2,2,4] Iwant an output as arr =[2,3]**

Below is my python Code

```
class Solution(object):
    def findErrorNums(self,nums):


        char_set = set()
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            if nums[i] not in char_set:
                char_set.add(nums[i])
            else:
                char_set.add(nums[i])
                char_set.add(nums[i]+1)
                return char_set


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = [1,2,2,4]
    Solution().findErrorNums(arr)
    print(arr)
```

The output that I am getting at the moment is same array.

Comment: This will help you to be able to find problems in your code: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: "The output that I am getting at the moment is same array." because you are literally printing the same array that is the input.

Comment: I am not using Python 3.x but below version of that

Comment: I made some changes and created a separate list and added the elements there and returned it but it's only passing 7 cases out of 49

Comment: Why do you assume that the array is sorted? The next number could be any number, not just `nums[i]+1`

Comment: Do you have the link to the question?

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/set-mismatch/submissions/  Here is the link

Answer (score 0):

The numbers are not guaranteed to be sorted, so you have to find both the duplicate and the missing one separately. You can calculate the missing one from the duplicated one and the expected sum of all numbers:

```
class Solution(object):
    def findErrorNums(self, nums):
        expected_sum = (n:=len(nums)) * (n+1) // 2  # sum from 1 to n
        diff = expected_sum - sum(nums)
        s = set()
        for num in nums:
            if num in s:
                return [num, num+diff]
            s.add(num)
```

Comment: They are sorted as they are numbers from 1 to n

Comment: "Numbers from 1 to n" does not imply they come in that order. And if they did, the duplication does not have to be next number, could be the previous. Anyway, check the testcases: the duplicates aren't even neighbours in many of them.

Comment: One testcase is for example: `[8,7,3,5,3,6,1,4]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use set operations to find the missing item by subtracting the items you have from the set of expected items.

The duplicate item will be the one that doesn't match its position in the sorted order.

```
s = [1,2,2,4]

expected  = range(1,len(s)+1)
missing,  = set(expected).difference(s)
duplicate = next(n for i,n in enumerate(sorted(s),1) if n != i) 

print([duplicate,missing]) # [2,3]
```